# Trouble finding memory leak (tracemalloc/objgraph/gc not helping)

Tags: python-3.x, memory-leaks

I have a network process that communicates over TCP collecting data, deserialising it and finally storing parts in a LevelDB key/value store (via [Plyvel](https://github.com/wbolster/plyvel)).

Slowly over time it will consume all available memory to the point that my whole system locks up (Ubuntu 18.04). I'm trying to diagnose the cause but I'm running out of ideas how to investigate further.

The main suspects I have in mind is the data streams we operate on to deserialise the objects. The general thing done there is: receive data from an [asyncio.StreamReader](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.StreamReader) and call `deserialize_from_bytes` (see next)

```
    @classmethod
    def deserialize_from_bytes(cls, data_stream: Union[bytes, bytearray]):
        """ Deserialize object from a byte array. """
        br = BinaryReader(stream=data_stream)
        inv_payload = cls()
        try:
            inv_payload.deserialize(br)
        except ValueError:
            return None
        finally:
            br.cleanup()
        return inv_payload
```

where `BinaryReader` initialises like this

```
   def __init__(self, stream: Union[io.BytesIO, bytes, bytearray]) -> None:
        super(BinaryReader, self).__init__()

        if isinstance(stream, (bytearray, bytes)):
            self._stream = io.BytesIO(stream)
        else:
            self._stream = stream
```

and `cleanup()` is a convenience wrapper for `self._stream.close()`

**What I've tried:**

1. I started with trying out the [display top 10](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html#display-the-top-10) snippet of `tracemalloc`. At a point in time where `/proc/$mypid/status` shows a memory usage of 2GB (by `VmSize`), the most consuming item from `tracemalloc` reports a mere 38MB, followed by the second and third being 3MB and 360Kb.

   This already raises a question; where is the other ~1.958 GB?
2. Not helped by the above output, I tried [objgraph](https://github.com/mgedmin/objgraph/). I break into the process with `pdb` and use

```
import objgraph
objgraph.show_most_common_types(limit=20)
```

to get

```
function                   16451
tuple                      11456
dict                       10371
weakref                    3058
list                       2893
cell                       2446
Traceback                  2277
Statistic                  2277
_Binding                   2109
getset_descriptor          1814
type                       1680
builtin_function_or_method 1469
wrapper_descriptor         1311
method_descriptor          1284
frozenset                  992
property                   983
module                     810
ModuleSpec                 808
SourceFileLoader           738
Attrs                      593
```

I don't see any objects specific to my program in that list (which could indicate references not being released). From other `objgraph` examples I found the above counts don't seem out of the ordinary.
I inspected a couple of `function` objects and always found something similar to this (asyncio related) which doesn't suggest any memory is leaking there

```
(Pdb) objgraph.at(0x10f309b70)
<function _run_coroutine.<locals>.step_next.<locals>.continue_ at 0x10f309b70>
```

Please correct me here if I'm missing something. Again, no step further

3. A final try to see if I can enforce any memory being released I manually run [gc.collect()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect). Repeatedly calling it gives values between 25-500 for number of unreachable objects. It doesn't trigger me as an issue (should it?). I also tried running the program with `gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK)` but that's generates so much output I can't make anything of it.

Any tips what I can try from here on?

Comment: Is `BinaryReader` your class?

Comment: Yes. you can find the whole file here: https://github.com/ixje/neo-python/blob/asyncio_alpha2/neo/Network/neonetwork/core/io/binary_reader.py

Comment: Have you tried to use memory allocation profiling tools line https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html to find lines with most memory allocation calls?

Comment: May the `data_stream` parameter prevent the `BinaryReader` from GarbageCollection at the end of the `deserialize_from_bytes` functional scope? As long as `data_stream` is not destroyed you keep creating new instances of `BinaryReader` each call without destroying them.

Comment: if that would be the case then I'd expect the BinaryReader class to show up in the objgraph

Comment: @ixje Did you come up with a way to narrow down the culprit by any chance?

Comment: @kazarey I have not, but I have also moved on from the project.

Comment: If you ask the current owner of the product to take a live core of your python process after it has become large but not so large that the system is so responsive, you can take a look at that core with [chap](https://github.com/vmware/chap).  Just make sure to set the /proc/*your-process-pid*/coredump_filter to 0x37 before taking the core.  Then start with **summarize used** or **summarize used /sortby bytes** from the **chap** prompt.